# JS regular expression works at regular-expressions.info, but not in my code

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string in JavaScript:

```
s = "</p><ol><li>First\n</li><li>Second\n</li></ol><p>"
```

Then I do this (to remove the outer "</p>...<p>"):

```
s = s.replace(/^<\/([^> ]+)[^>]*>(.*)<\1>$/,"$2");
```

Nothing happens (s is unchanged, and using match() returns false), but if I go try it at http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html, it works!

I've tried all sorts of things (creating a separate regExp object, using //g, taking out the ^$, replacing [^> ]+ with [a-z0-9]*...) but nothing makes any difference.

It's driving me nuts. can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is using Regular Expressions to parse HTML. HTML is not a Regular Language. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags More than that, it's invalid HTML

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: While that's a fun answer, it's completely incorrect in this case. OP is just trying to remove a starting tag, and matching ending tag, for this a regex will do perfectly fine.

Comment: It's not about being fun, it's about being completely wrong in the approach. Using a RegExp to parse HTML is wrong, HTML is not a regular language, it's _very_ easy to show that it's impossible to build a DFA to parse it. Even if it's possible to build such a DFA (or Regex) for this specific case, i t's the wrong tool to approach this problem. Just because it's possible doesn't mean one should do it.

Comment: Note that the problem here is that the string starts with a closing tag, and ends with an opening tag. That's why I'm using an RE: it isn't well-formed HTML.

Comment: Problem now solved as per MikeM below. And meanwhile if anyone took BenjaminGruenbaum's advice they'd still be crafting an LL(k) sledgehammer for a very very small RE nut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply that `.` does not match newlines `\n`.

If you replace the `.*` with `[\s\S]*`, your regex should work.

`[\s\S]` means match any space or non-space character, which equates to match *any* character.

Comment: Magic. Thank you very much. (I tried //s earlier and it didn't work; doesn't JS support this?)

Comment: @user1636349. No, JS doesn't have a single-line mode.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't realised. Spot the newbie.